# Correct syntax to invoke method by name

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke

The code below is correctly finding the class and method but it gives the following error on `method.Invoke(this, null);`

```
System.Reflection.TargetException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232829
  Message=Object does not match target type.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:.....
```

What is the correct syntax to invoke a void method?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;

namespace ProjectXYZ
{
    class NavigateOptions
    {


        public bool runMethod(string debug_selectedClass)
        {
            Type t = Type.GetType("ProjectXYZ." + debug_selectedClass);
            MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("test");
            if (method.IsStatic)
                method.Invoke(null, null);
            else
                method.Invoke(this, null);

            return true;

        }
    }

    public class Option72
    {
        public void test()
        {
            string hasItRun = "Yes";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` (the class from which you are calling the method) is not the class where the `test()` method is defined in. You have to supply an instance of that class (the one indicated by `debug_selectedClass`) to invoke a non-static method on it.

If it has an empty constructor, you could do:

```
if (method.IsStatic)
    method.Invoke(null, null);
else
{
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    method.Invoke(instance, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One quick related question, is it possible to test for an empty constructor similar to  `if (method.IsStatic)`, eg `if (method.???)`

Comment: You can check whether `t.GetConstructor(new Type[0])` returns a `ConstructorInfo` or `null`.